# In roadmap markers too much west, in satellite map OK while labels checked

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In http://www.groenteruilen.nl/index2.html the markers (in roadmap) show too much west. When choosing the satellite mode, the markers show up OK if only the label-checkbox is checked. 
So there's a difference in the position of the roadmap and the sattelite map.

Maybe related: the zoom buttons do not work.